# Mysql 5.7 Pulling every time

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, yarnpkg

yarn database:start

I am making a react js project and i am using the above command and it pulls mysql 5.7 library every time on restart. I don't want to download it every time what is the problem. i am working on ubuntu 18.0.4

Pull everytime

```
latest: Pulling from library/mysql

aa18ad1a0d33: Pull complete
fdb8d83dece3: Pull complete
75b6ce7b50d3: Pull complete
ed1d0a3a64e4: Pull complete
8eb36a82c85b: Pull complete
41be6f1a1c40: Pull complete
0e1b414eac71: Pull complete
914c28654a91: Pull complete
587693eb988c: Pull complete
b183c3585729: Pull complete
315e21657aa4: Pull complete
```

Digest: sha256:0dc3dacb751ef46a6647234abdec2d47400f0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the memory storage of the system it is problem due to memory storage